# If $h$ is measurable and $fh \in L^q$ for all $f \in L^p$ then $f \mapsto fh$ is a continuous map from $L^p$ to $L^q$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Showing this is a problem from Axler's textbook on Real Analysis.

$q$ is not the dual exponent of $p$, necessarily, they both just satisfy $1 \leq p, q\leq \infty$

My idea was to use the Closed Graph Theorem:

$(f_k, hf_k) \to (f, w)$. It would suffice to show that a subsequence converges to $(f, hf)$.
Because $f_k \to f$ in $p$-norm, I can take a subsequence that converges to $f$ pointwise a.e.: $f_{n_k}(x) \to f(x)$. So if I could show that $hf_{n_k} \longrightarrow hf$ in $q$-norm, I would be done. What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\|hf - hf_{k_n}\|_q = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int |hf - hf_{k_n}|^q d\mu = \int \lim_{n \to \infty}|hf(x) - hf_{k_n}(x)|^qd\mu = 0$

This would show that $hf_k \longrightarrow hf$.

But I can't find a dominating sequence in order to pass the limit into the integral. It seems like I would need to claim that $f \mapsto hf$ is bounded, which is what I'm trying to prove.

Is this approach hopeless? Hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making things complicated.  $f_n \to f$ in $L^{p}$  and $hf_n \to w$ in $L^{q}$ implies $f_k \to f$ almost everywhere and $hf_k \to w$ almost everywhere along some subsequence. Hence,  $w=hf $ almost everywhere which proves that the graph is closed.